# Does the Stream in the flutter streambuilder updates itself?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I decided to use Streambuilder to get my data from Firestore. 
However, when I want to do a query (where or orderBy) that is dynamic (based on the value emitted by the text field), my stream only shows the data that was initially downloaded. Letting me think that the Streambuilder stream doesn't change/update it's value unless changes in the data backend take place. Is this correct? If yes, how can I update the value of my stream in the StreamBuilder to pull the data based on my query? Thx.

I also read that the you set your stream outside the StreamBuilder and should be place in the initState or something. I'm not sure of the exact meaning. I tried doing that but the stream is not being pass to the streambuilder stream via the variable if you place it in the initState.

Example Code:

```
var query;
var queryController;

...

//TextField
return Column(
  children: [ 
    TextField(
      controller = queryController,  
    ),
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed() {
        setState(() {
          query = queryController.text;
        });
      }  
    )
]);

.... 

//StreamBuilder with firestore steam snapshot
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: firestore.instance.collection('products').where('search_field', isEqualTo: query).orderBy('timestamp', descending: false).snapshots();
  builder (context, snapshot) {

    ... //if has data, show data the widget 
    return MyWidget(snapshot.data);
  }
)
```

Comment: Since you're listening to `snapshots()`, the stream *will* update whenever there's a change to the underlying data. If that doesn't translate into updates on your screen, it's most likely going wrong somewhere downstream in the rendering. But it's impossible to say where based on the info you provide.